# How to navigate to home page? - python django

Tags: python, django

I have created an Index page using HTML and have given an URL for "Home" button, In a way that when the home button is clicked the page navigates from Index page to home page. But it doesn't navigate to home page, when clicked in URL address the address changes to the specified location correctly but the page displayed is still the Index page.

```html
<div class="top-menu">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <div id="fh5co-logo"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">TrainedbySamson<span>.</span></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 text-right menu-1">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'tbs_home:home' %}">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% static 'gallery.html' %}">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% static 'about.html' %}">Trainer</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% static 'pricing.html' %}">Pricing</a></li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="{% static 'blog.html' %}">Blog</a>
```

tbs_home/urls.py:

```html
urlpatterns = [
    
    path('home',views.home, name='home'), 
    
]
```

tbs_home/views.py:

```html
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

templates/home.html:

```html
{% load static %}

 
{% block content%}

<h1 style = "font-family:Georgia;font:40px;font-style:normal;">Hi! {{name}}</h1>


<form action="add" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Enter 1st num : <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd num : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

So when I click the home button according to the code the page should navigate to home.html page?. But it stays in the same Index page, thanks in advance.

Comment: try this <a href="{% url  'home' %}"> or put app_name= 'tbs_home' in urls.py

Comment: When I change that I get error message"django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name." when I run the server

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code , It is working fine.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPPYl.png)

**settings.py**

> configure apps & templates.

**urls.py:**

```
import views from app
path('', views.homeone, name='home'),
```

**Views.py:**

```
def homeone(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

**Home.html**

```html
{% load static %}


<div class="top-menu">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <div id="fh5co-logo">TrainedbySamson<span>.</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 text-right menu-1">
                        <ul>
{#                            <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'tbs_home' %}">Home</a></li>#}
                            <li><a href="{% url "home" %}"> Home2 </a>  </li>
                            <li><a href="{% static 'gallery.html' %}">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% static 'about.html' %}">Trainer</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% static 'pricing.html' %}">Pricing</a></li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="{% static 'blog.html' %}">Blog</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

{% block content%}

<h1 style = "font-family:Georgia;font:40px;font-style:normal;">Cool&#128521 {{name}}</h1>


<form action="add" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Enter 1st num : <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd num : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The code that you've mentioned in home.html I have kept it in Index.html separately because index.html page is the main page

Comment: I tried your code its not navigating to home.html, thanks

Comment: If you change in html page names, then you need to change views and urls too.

Comment: My code is working perfectly and also shown screenshot. First of all, you need to try with same code, understand it clearly.  After that you need to modify. Good day.

Answer (score 0):

You should add app_name = 'tbs_home' after import libraries urls.py file.  If the same problem persists, add a print ("check home function") to see if it goes into the home function in views.py.

Comment: from django.urls  import path
from . import views #
from .views import home
app_name = "tbs_home"

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('home',views.home, name='home'), 
    
]

Comment: No, can you suggest any other method?

Comment: Can you share github link or we can look at the code together